# What is the difference between two setState expressions in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

SetState function accepts void Function as an argument. In case of the first expression, everything works fine, however using the lambda expression produces an error. Doesn't the second expression also defines a void function?

```
setState(() {
  _count++;
});

setState(() => {
  _count++;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot use curly brackets when you use lambda functions so if you try the code below, it would work exactly like the first setState()

```
setState(
    () => _count++;
);
```

The general syntax for lambda functions is

```
return_type function_name(arguments) => expression;
```

And as you can see, There are no curly brackets.

[This](https://dev.to/jay_tillu/lambda-functions-in-dart-3eih) is a good article as well which can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In flutter, you can use

```
(){ 
     // one or multiple expressions
     // with/out a return value/type
   }
```

or `() => single_line_expression;`

This return type of the `single_line_expression` will be inferred from the evaluation of the expression.

The arrow operator implies that the return value is the return value of the `single_line_expression` which can be anything depending on the return type of the `single_line_expression`.

In the case of

```
setState(() => {    // retun type here is set {} with one value _count++ 
  _count++;         // comman causes syntax error. 
});
```

you are trying to return a set with value _count++ which is not null as expected by setState and there is also a syntax error caused by the `;` because set elements are separated by `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing:

```dart
setState(() => {
  count++, 
});
```

is equivalent to writing:

```dart
Set<int> something = { count++ };
setState(() => something);
```

This is unlikely what you want, as you do not care about that `Set`.

Instead, do:

```dart
setState(() {
  count++;
});
```

This will not create an intermediary `Set`.